# Why does an indentation error cause shadowing from outer scopes

Tags: python, scope

I'm working on a game called Scuba Adventure, and while trying to find the source of an attribute error I got another error saying something like "object shadows from outer scope." I found the source of the error to be indentation. When defining a class called Bubble that controlled the bubble object and the sprite group I accidentally indented the methods within the `def __init__()`. My class was something like this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bubble(Sprite):
    """A class that manages bubbles released from the diver."""

    def __init__(self, sa_game):
        """create a bubble object at the diver's current position."""
        super().__init__()
        """Some attributes"""
        "
        "

        # import the bubble image
        """Code to import the bubble image"""

        # Store the bubble's position as a decimal value
        """ """

        def update(self):
           """Move the bubble up the screen."""
           # Method to update the decimal position of the bubble
           

        def blit_bubble(self):
           """Method to draw the bubble at the diver's current location"""
```

The function bodies themselves don't matter. But what I'm wondering is what does "shadowing from outer scope" mean and why would an indentation error throw it. I'm still a beginner, so this concept might be new to me

Answer (score 0):

It means the methods existed in two places, and the ones inside `__init__` would override (shadow) whatever definition they had outside this scope.

Comment: Is this part of base Python? I'm guessing it's from Pygame

Comment: Ah, it looks like linting instead and I've conflated "error" with the warning. nm

Comment: It's from Pygame

Comment: @tripleee, so the update() method I get that that would cause overshadowing, because I used other update() functions in other classes. But blit_bubble() is a method unique to this class other than the function call in the main loop. So in this case, blit_bubble() would be overshadowed as well?

Comment: If there is no other definitien then technically no, but the static code analyzer might not be able to exclude the possibility that there is another definition, though it can't see it, or correctly but slightly misleadingly warning you about shadowing an undefined reference.